# How to check Apache version in Puppet

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, puppet

I need to apply a different access control configuration depending on whether a server is using Apache 2.2 or 2.4. Presumably, this requires an `if` check on the version of Apache.

I would like to know if this is what I should be doing:

```
if versioncmp($apache_version, '2.4') >= 0 {
  requires     => 'all denied',
else
  order        => 'deny,allow',
  deny         => 'from all',
}
```

One concern I have with this is that it appears to be checking the explicit version. What if the version is actually 2.4.6?

`$apache_version` is assigned at the top of the class as

```
$apache_version =  $::apache::apache_version
```

I don't even know if that is going to work because I'm not sure the class is even aware of the `::apache` module.

Despite seeing comments that such checks should not be done within a resource (`apache::vhost` in this case), I embedded the check. Reason being that I'm not sure how I would do a multiline variable assignment such that I could substitute

```
order    => 'deny,allow',
deny     => 'from all',
```

with something like

```
else
  $apache2.2_ac
}
```

If someone can point me in the proper direction on that as well I'd be grateful.

Comment: Which Apache Puppet module are you using?

Comment: I ran `puppet module list` but it shows that none are installed: `/etc/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)`. I'm guessing the Apache module is included. The puppet version is 3.8.7.

Comment: Are you writing your own module then? It's hard to answer your questions without knowing where the class is coming from. If it's the official Puppet Apache module, then $apache_version default value [will be 2.2 or 2.4 based on the operating system default](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/version.pp) Apache. (It doesn't consider if you are using a custom Apache.)

Comment: @AaronCopley Not a custom module. I'm assuming it shipped with Puppet.

Comment: I believe this is what I'm using: http://www.puppetmodule.info/github/simp/puppetlabs-apache/puppet_classes/apache. I guess not a module but a built-in class.

Comment: Another idea, you do not need to do this with Puppet at all. In Apache configuration, you can use the `If` directive to put things in action only if specific version. Which means you can have both your 2.2 and 2.4 directives in the same file and let Apache use the appropriate one automatically when it starts, which removes the need to maintain more than one file and decide which one to install where. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if and using SERVER_SOFTWARE or API_VERSION from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The Apache config is managed by puppet and puppet is currently a mess. I see what you are saying in that the apache config does have some basic logic capability, but unfortunately, any changes to the config would be overwritten by the next puppet run.

Comment: puppet can manage the configuration file, but you could have only one Apache configuration file (with both directives for 2.2 and 2.4 in it with proper `If` statement), instead of 2. So that you have nothing to worry about the Apache version in puppet, it is the same single file everywhere.